# Microdata specification mandates value for 'itemscope' attribute?

Tags: microdata

I've been filling my website with Microdata (using recommended metadata / schema.org) for rich search results in search engines.

After finishing things up and testing with Google Rich Snippet Tool everything looks ok but now when I access my website with an Android browser I get the following message:

> Specification mandate value for attribute `itemscope`

This looks like an error related with `itemscope` attribute being defined without a value, but that is how Microdata defines its standard.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue? Microdata defines the `itemscope` attribute without value (interesting stuff as it produces invalid XML and it’s being defined by Web giants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is not XML. Boolean attributes do not need an explicit value. See the spec here for examples.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

If there is a browser that does not handle this style of attribute, you ought to feel free to use the empty string form. Do not worry that the Microdata specification uses a different form, since they mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes I ended up using the empty string but this just doesn't feel right.

Comment: HTML5 markup needs an upgrade. It hasn't changed in 30 years. This would enable 1000's of editors and parsers to support it via XML. I propose changes https://www.radii8.com/blog/?p=1268

Answer (score 0):

It looks like defining `itemscope=""` works, but this goes against Microdata specification.